# Disable events from extra keyboard keys on notebook

Tags: 14.04, keyboard

How can I disable events like "fly mode", "turn of screen" which locate in F1-F12 buttons on my notebook?
I need those buttons for hotkeys in my IDE and I always call this events when I misclicked and pressed single F1-F12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my laptop (Lenovo) this can be disabled in BIOS.

Comment: I have Lenovo too, I will check BIOS setting later, thank you